# Change back item title with push Segue

Tags: ios5, uistoryboardsegue

I'm using a push segue for showing a new ViewController in my Storyboard. By default, the back bar item on the pushed navigation controller has the title of the "previous" (underlaying) controller.

In order to change the title of the back bar item to, e.g., "Back" I implemented the following in the ViewController which gets pushed:

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";
}
```

But this doesn't change the title of the back bar item. I've also tried to use a newly created UIBarButtonItem with the same result: the back bar item doesn't change.

Another approach was the set the back bar item like in `prepareForSegue` in the controller where the segue is executed.

```c
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"pushViewController"]) {
        UIViewController *viewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";
    }
}
```

With the same result: the back bar item title doesn't change. So how can i easily change the title of the back bar item? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To be a bit more specific than Marco's answer, what you're looking for is this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{        
    self.title = @"Back";
    // ...
}
```

Note that this is IMHO quite annoying, because you could potentially end up having to have a whole state machine centered around what "self.title" should be at the current instant in time, rather than just having each scene in the storyboard know what the back button should say.

Answer (score 2):

Set navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title in the source view controller, not the destination view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Add title for back bar item into "Storyboard->VC->NavigationItem" example as "Back", 
and when prepare segue, set:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"Need a Title :)";
```